# Prevent loading the content of a hidden div

Tags: jquery, css

this is my html :

```
<ul id="navigationMenu">
<li>
    <a class="home" href="#">
        <span> i need to prevent loading this content</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a class="about" href="#">
        <span><img src="http://webdesigntunes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Minimalistic-Navigation-Menu.jpg" /> </span>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
     <a class="services" href="#">
        <span>Services</span>
     </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a class="portfolio" href="#">
        <span>Portfolio</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a class="contact" href="#">
        <span>Contact us</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

sorry i not able to put css !

but i hide li with overflow:hidden and when hover overflow:visible

i need to prevent a browser from load hidden li content until the visitor show "li" by hover on another div

Comment: Please add your CSS and JS code to the question.

Comment: the content will always be loaded by browser. and u can just hide it, the `li` will be in the sourcecode tho. you can realize it by adding the `li` asynchrone

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="list">
  <a class="about" href="#">
    <span><img src="http://webdesigntunes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Sweet-Tabbed.jpg"   /> </span>
  </a>
</li>


$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#list').hide();

   $('#yourdiv').hover(function()
   {
     $('#list').show();
   },

  function()
  {
    //in case you want to hide it again on mouseout else leave this function empty
    $('#list').hide();  
  }
  );

});
```

Comment: i dont need to just hide it , but prevent load his content also ! tahnx

Comment: @techno do you mean that you don't want the element on page load,that is no `<li id="list"></li>` on page load?

Comment: i have 3 .js requests inside this hidden element , when the page load , i need to load all content in the page but not this 3 .js files . the browser start load it after li is shown ..

Answer (score 0):

1. assign an ID to the li element.
2. in your CSS, assign    "display:none" to this ID.
3. on the other div, add an onHover trigger for showElement.
4. add the following javascript:

   function showElement()
   {
   document.getElementById("li element id").style.display="block";
   }

Comment: i dont need to just hide it , but prevent load his content also ! tahnx

Comment: @techno If you want something to not be loaded in the DOM, you need to leave it out of the page and then get it via an AJAX call. Which in turn means that you need to write a serverside web service so you have an AJAX endpoint.

Comment: @nzll i have 3 .js requests inside this hidden element , when the page load , i need to load all content in the page but not this 3 .js files . the browser start load it after li is shown ..how i can do that with ajax ?

Comment: You're approaching it from the wrong angle, then. If you want those 3 JS scripts to not execute until you've hovered over the element, you need to link the loading of those JS files to the hover event of the element. You can use JQuery.GetScript() to do this. more info at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/